# Marquee Animation In Safari

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, safari

I'm trying to recreate a marquee tag using CSS animations.  Works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but for some reason in Safari(12.0.1), the animation either won't play or won't play correctly until I switch tabs.

Here's my CSS:

```
.marquee{
    width:100%;
    background-color:rgba(56, 38, 48, .8);
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height:51px;
}

.marquee p {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 100%;
    animation: marquee 120s linear -3s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: marquee 120s linear -3s infinite;
    color: white;
}

@-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { transform: translate(0,0); }
    100% { transform translate(-100%, 0); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes marquee {
    0%   { -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0); }
}
```

HTML: This is a React application.  Before the component mounts, it fetches a group of tickers and their values, then feeds them into a component that renders them:

```
componentWillMount(){
    const params = {
      method:'POST',
      body:'key=1234567',
      headers: {
        "Content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
      },
    }
    fetch('/tickers', params)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
          const tickers = Object.assign({}, data)
          this.setState({tickers})
          console.log(this.state.tickers)
        }
      )
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(`could not fetch: ${err}`)
        })

  }
```

The tickers then get fed into this component where the marquee effect is being applied:

```
const Tickerbar = (props) => {
  const displayNameStyle = {
    color:'white',
  }

  const midStyle = {
    color:'#CDBFBF',
    marginRight:'20px'
  }

  const displayNames = Object.keys(props.tickers)
  const displayNameAndMid = displayNames.map(cusip => {
    return(
        <span key={cusip}>
          <span style={displayNameStyle}>
            <b>{cusip.split('/').join('.')}:</b>
          </span>

          <span style={midStyle}>
            <b>{(props.tickers[cusip]).toFixed(2)}</b>
          </span>
        </span>
  )
  })
  return(
    <div className="marquee">
      <p>
        {displayNameAndMid}
      </p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

For reference, I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

EDIT: I made a separate HTML markup using the same CSS, and it works fine.  So I believe the problem has to do with getting the data from the database and rendering it to the component

EDIT: I seem to have some success adding by adding a 1 second delay to the animation time.  I guess this gives the component time to fetch the tickers and render the animation.

Comment: The snippet of code you have posted works in the latest Safari for me when I use the following HTML structure `<div class="marquee">
  <p>
    test
  </p>
</div>` Are you able to share your actual HTML structure and the version of Safari / Mac osx you are using?

Comment: Sure thing.  Updated.

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue.
https://www.nps.gov/applications/glac/dashboard/
Safari only

Comment: I think I managed to fix this by adding a delay to the animation scroll.  Did you try that?